# 404 for pub/static files

Tags: magento2.2.3, 404-page, file-permissions

After **installing Magento 2.3** on the server, when I run the URL I am receiving **404** for **`pub/static`**.

I have given **proper permission** to magento **folders**. Also set ownership to **apache** for the **codebase**.

Now, while looking into `pub/static` folder, I found the user & group is set to **root instead of apache**. Is this causing issue to load the static content in Magento? If so, how can I set the ownership of newly created folders?

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly run below commands and check again

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Comment: Hi Suresh,
Thanks but I have tried running above commands but still receiving 404.

Comment: Check pub folder .htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

1. In `app/etc/di.xml`, `name="view_preprocessed"` section,  update :

   `Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink`

   to

   `Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy`
   .
2. Remove the **content** of `pub/static` = `rm -rf pub/static/*` and `var/view_preprocessed` = `rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/*`
3. Set them (`pub/static`, `var/view_preprocessed`) the ownership as `www-data` with chmod `775`
4. Flush the cache : `php bin/magento c:f`
5. Deploy the static-content : `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`

Answer (score 0):

**1) Check File Permissions**

For your file-permission question specifically, the first time I set up Magento 2 I had several file permission errors.

I started over and followed the Adobe documentation line by line. No more permission errors:

https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/installation-guide/prerequisites/web-server/nginx.html

Here is a quick summary of just the file-permission commands:

*find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} +*

*find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} +*

*chown -R :www-data .*

*chmod u+x bin/magento*

**2) Check Config Parameters**

I would check these config parameters in your core_config_data table in the database:

- web/secure/base_url (make sure it matches your Magento URL)
- web/unsecure/base_url (make sure it matches your Magento URL)
- web/secure/use_in_adminhtml (mine is set to 1)
- web/secure/use_in_frontend (mine is set to 1)

**3) Check Deploy Mode**

Finally, make sure you are in the right deploy mode, depending on if you are in dev or production:

*php bin/magento deploy:mode:show*